# .NET Window Forms local database

Tags: .net, winforms, dataset

I just started writing a Windows Forms Application and I'd like to store data in a Database but not in an actual DB Server.. something like SQLite (local, server independent).

Does .NET have anything like this out of the box? I looked into DataSets but I'm have a hard time populating it.

Any pointers are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Does the data need to persist across application restarts?  SQLite has an ADO.Net driver so if you need to store database in a database-like way, you might as well actually use a database.

Comment: Yes, the data is a bunch of sentences I rather have in a db than in an array in the code. I was wondering if "Data:DataSet" is what I'm looking for... the 3 books that I have go straight to connecting to a sql server db. I'll end up using SQLite if I can't find a native solution for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to save a huge amount of data you can use XML or even JSON.
With [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) you can serialize objects and write them to a text file, then read json file and get your data back.

```
// define you data type
class MyData
{
   ...
}

// using MyData
string jsonString= myDaJsonConvert.SerializeObject<List<Profile>>(data);
List<Profile> data = myDaJsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Profile>>(jsonString);
```

EDIT 1:

Even if its System.Data.SQlite assembly is outdated this legacy [setup](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/files/latest/download?source=files) file contains a "Designer" component for ADO.NET 2.0 which might simplify a lot the Dataset creation routine. Please remember to update SQlite libraries from this [site](http://system.data.sqlite.org/) later.

Comment: I'm familiar manipulating xml/json, but I do want to use a db like model (a la sqlite) since it's a very basic game. I don't want people to just open up the external file and see all the data. Thanks for your suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

You can try **SQL Server Compact**, i didn't used it, but it seems that it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Consider Sql Server Compact edition, you can find instruction how to add it to your project [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983322.aspx).
Below sample code to retrieve data from the table MyTable containing column Id in database file MyDb.sdf, you also need to add System.Data.SqlServerCe assembly reference and namespace System.Data.SqlServerCe

```
using (SqlCeConnection ceConn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MyDb.sdf"))
using (SqlCeCommand ceCmd = new SqlCeCommand("select Id from MyTable", ceConn))
{
    ceConn.Open();
    SqlCeDataReader dataR = ceCmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dataR.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dataR["Id"].ToString());
    }
}
```