# Deploying SQL server with VS 2012 application

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I'm working on a winform application using VS2012 (.NET 4). I use SQL Server for my database affairs, I can run this application smoothly on my development systems (which have VS 2012 installed) but when I give EXE and my MDF files to someone who don't have VS2012 installed, they get an SQL server exception (also program runs but they cannot use database features), I think problem is that they don't have SQL server installed, how can I solve this problem? what should I give to my users? Is there any difference between Debug and Release versions? I deploy Debug EXE which runs but as mentioned SQL server features are not usable

Comment: Since your application uses an SQL Server database, then your clients must have SQL Server installed on their systems.

Comment: Full SQL Server might not be what you want unless you plan to host it and connect remotely from the winforms application.  If you want local DB for your winforms app, you will want to use something else.  Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088157/net-window-forms-local-database.  If your data model is simple, there's SQLite.  If you want to stick with MS, try SQL Server Compact (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/compact.aspx).

Comment: where can I find sql server client edition?