# how to create .net application with database for my client

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, winforms

I have created a .Net application which has some functionality to store and retrieve records from SQL database.

But now I have to create a setup of this application and install it on client side. But I don't know how to do that. Plus database functionality should also work on client end I mean he should be able to add and delete the records through program.

I have to create a setup for my .net application which also consist database file all connectivity. So when I install it on client machine it should not ask for database or connectivity stuff.

Comment: Google for setup and deployment. An example from [**codeproject**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12548/Visual-Studio-Windows-Application-Setup-Project).

Comment: Go through [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Oybek can you provide me any other link where I can find such information. As I have to create a setup for my .net application which also consist database. And when I install it on client machine it should not ask for database.

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: First of all what is your database? What is your application type? Is it WPF or WinForms? Are there special things that one needs to consider? As for me, I'd do an installer using WinRAR SFX. It possesses almost perfect installer capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have created SQL Server Database for your WinForms application then you would probably need to deploy same SQL Server version that you used to the clients server/PC.

Otherwise you will need to restructure your code for SQL ServerCE or whichever database you would use.

SQL Server compact download: http://www.microsoft.com/cs-cz/download/details.aspx?id=17876

You will just need to pass the .sdf file to your WinForms project and use similar syntax as for SQL Server.

E.g.

```
SqlCeConnection conn = 
     new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\dbJournal.sdf");
conn.Open();
```

Note: That you could install only SQL Server Express which is NOT full version of SQL Server and doesn't require that much disk space and processing power.

SQL Server Express download: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062

Recommend to see (SQL CE): [.NET Window Forms local database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088157/net-window-forms-local-database)

Comment: I'm using VS 2013 and SQLserver 2012, It is a very simple windows forms application which has user interface to store the values in database and a gridview control to view the records. But I have to create a setup for it so I can install it on a different machine. Actually it's my college project.

Comment: Yes I understood that, now you need to deploy the application to computer to present functionality right? If you didn't needed to use SQL Server, then I would go and use SQL Compact, if your code is not really hard and complex to edit for SQL CE syntax. OR Why not connect to your existing SQL Server after deploying the application? Do you have server with public connection?

Comment: Actually computer where I have to install this application does not have any type of connectivity neither internet nor any LAN or SERVER.

Comment: Then the only solution is SQL Server CE. Do you need any help with it?

Comment: Yes. Please help me as I have never used SQL Server CE.

Comment: Add Database file to your existing project, Then Change SqlConnection, SqlCommand to SqlCeConnection, SqlCeCommand and so on.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12548/Visual-Studio-Windows-Application-Setup-Project) article will be helpful for creating set up. For Database support, add compact edition of your database into setup file.